# Calculate the average of multiple columns, based on value of the first column

Tags: python, pandas

Giving the following column

| Name | score1 | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 100 | 120 | 900 |
| Lisa | 40 | 120 | 90 |
| Bob | 590 | 490 | 80 |
| Tim | 100 | 120 | 900 |
| Tim | 40 | 120 | 90 |
| Bob | 590 | 490 | 80 |

I would like to calculate the average of all columns, for each person in the Name column.
So for Bob, I would like to get one average of all 9 values.

I know that the code below will calculate the average of multiple columns. How can I make it calculate the average for all rows with the same name?

```
df['averages'] = df[['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3']].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply) and [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
df.set_index('Name').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: np.mean(g.to_numpy()))
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Or compute the sum and divide by the number of cells:

```
g = df.groupby('Name')

out = g.sum().sum(axis=1).div(g['Name'].size()*(df.shape[1]-1))
```

Output:

```
Name
Bob     382.222222
Lisa     83.333333
Tim     228.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Name', aggfunc='mean').mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Name
Bob     382.222222
Lisa     83.333333
Tim     228.333333
dtype: float64
```